# How to enable trace for response header in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

The api managment is connected to backend service fabric. From the tutorial through ARM template I created the Api and configured to service fabric service. When I do test from the portal I get trace

Then from the portal I create another api and configure to the same service fabric service then I test from there I get the following message for trace.

As you can see I am passing subscription key and trace to true

I am the administrator

Also noticed when I put the api under product created through the arm template I get trace. when for the product created from portal and associating this API I do not get trace. Is there a product level trace configuration?

> Trace is not available because response does not contain
>   Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location header.

Request header

```
GET doctor/v1/api/v1/Appointments HTTP/1.1

Host: dev-oasys-apimgmt.azure-api.net Cache-Control: no-cache
Ocp-Apim-Trace: true 
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
```

Comment: Do both products require subscription?

Comment: yes both require subscription key

Comment: Could you double check that response indeed does not contain "Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location" header? Sometimes UI may not detect it.